# Alphabets in x , y coordinates of Elliptic graph

Tags: ethereum, private-key, elliptic-curve, wallet

I was reading about the ethereum address generation process. I am very confused that when Private key generated is processed under "Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm" , we get a public key which is a point on graph. We take x & y co-ordinate of that point. Below is a sample of such process

[Image showing x & y co-ordinate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujQu2.png)

I am not able to understand is how can we have alphabets in the co-ordinates. I think it should have only numbers. I know that public key is denoted in hexadecimal format but how come co-ordinates have alphabets in it . Can anyone please explain it to me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The x and y coordinates are also represented in hexadecimal. For example:

`(b8b, 24f) (hex) = (2955, 591) (decimal)`